# Trying to build a hook into plotly for ggrepel (geom_text_repel)

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, plotly, ggrepel

The link below talks about how you can build a hook into plotly using the `gets3methods` call with `to.basic`. However, this only works for geoms that that be broken down into simpler geoms (`geom_line` to `geom_path`). For `geom_text_repel` I'm not sure that possible.

It goes on to mention that you have to create a custom method for the `geom2trace`. How would one go about doing this? I'm new to the S3 data guidelines and doing something like this, so I'm not exactly sure where to even start here.

If I run the `methods(geom2trace)` I get:

```
> methods(geom2trace)
 [1] geom2trace.default*       geom2trace.GeomBar*       geom2trace.GeomBlank*     geom2trace.GeomBoxplot*   geom2trace.GeomErrorbar* 
 [6] geom2trace.GeomErrorbarh* geom2trace.GeomPath*      geom2trace.GeomPoint*     geom2trace.GeomPolygon*   geom2trace.GeomText*     
[11] geom2trace.GeomTile*     
see '?methods' for accessing help and source code
```

and I see a `geom2trace.GeomText` which seems like something that is needed here.

Any guidance here would be a huge help in me trying to create an interactive wordcloud! Happy to share the outcome of this project as well.

> In more complicated cases, where your custom geom can not be converted
>   to a lower level geom, a custom method for the geom2trace() generic is
>   required (methods(geom2trace) lists all the basic geoms that we
>   natively support). This method should involve a conversion from a data
>   frame to a list-like object conforming to the plotly.js figure
>   reference.

https://plotly-book.cpsievert.me/translating-custom-ggplot2-geoms.html